# special function in specific section

Tags: linux-kernel

i want to put some functions in specific section

i add
include/asm-generic/vmlinux.lds.h:

`#define MY_TEXT                                                    \
               ALIGN_FUNCTION();                                       \
               VMLINUX_SYMBOL(__my_text_start) = .;                  \
               *(.my.text)                                           \
               VMLINUX_SYMBOL(__my_text_end) = .;`

arch/arm/kernel/vmlinux.lds.S:

`...
TEXT_TEXT
MY_TEXT
SCHED_TEXT
...`

my code:

`#define __my __attribute__((section(".my.text")))
int __my my_test(int i)
{
...
...
}`

but the compiler show:

/tmp/ccp1mtiA.s: Assembler messages:

/tmp/ccp1mtiA.s:13: Warning: setting incorrect section type for .my.text

/tmp/ccp1mtiA.s:13: Warning: setting incorrect section attributes for .my.text

how to fix the warning? 
i change to

`int __sche  my_test(int i)`

the warning is missed, i guess my section is not define well.

thanks

Comment: not sure why, but if i use .rel.text  the warning comes, if i changed to .my, the define works well. Maybe the .rel means something in gcc as

Answer (score 0):

You can control sections for your code with the `section` attribute (taken nearly verbatim from the [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bsection_007d-function-attribute-3111)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void foobar (void) __attribute__ ((section (.bar.text)));

void foobar()
{
   printf("asdf");
}

int main()
{
   foobar();
}
```

Build with `gcc -o sec.exe sec.cpp`.  Examining the output from `objdump -h sec.exe`, we see a section named .bar.text:

```
sec.exe:     file format pei-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         00001d10  0000000000401000  0000000000401000  00000400  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .bar.text     0000001c  0000000000403000  0000000000403000  00002200  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  2 .data         000000a0  0000000000404000  0000000000404000  00002400  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  3 .rdata        00000978  0000000000405000  0000000000405000  00002600  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .pdata        00000240  0000000000406000  0000000000406000  00003000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  5 .xdata        0000020c  0000000000407000  0000000000407000  00003400  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  6 .bss          000009b0  0000000000408000  0000000000408000  00000000  2**5
                  ALLOC
  7 .idata        000007c8  0000000000409000  0000000000409000  00003800  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  8 .CRT          00000068  000000000040a000  000000000040a000  00004000  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  9 .tls          00000068  000000000040b000  000000000040b000  00004200  2**5
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 10 .debug_aranges 00000050  000000000040c000  000000000040c000  00004400  2**4
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 11 .debug_info   00000df5  000000000040d000  000000000040d000  00004600  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 12 .debug_abbrev 00000087  000000000040e000  000000000040e000  00005400  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 13 .debug_line   00000119  000000000040f000  000000000040f000  00005600  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 14 .debug_frame  00000048  0000000000410000  0000000000410000  00005800  2**3
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
```

Be aware that some compile options can end up re-combining sections.

Comment: thanks for your information, but my code is built-in linux kernel, i am not sure why my modification shows warning.

Comment: Possibly because you aren't putting the attribute on the prototype?

Comment: i just tried the syntax like yours, it still does not work :(

Comment: And what does "it does not work" look like?  Did you dump the contents of the executable and find that the code wasn't put in the section?  Or by some other means?

Comment: from objdump, the section seems correct,  i just wonder why the warning is there. i am afraid it may cause some potential issues and want to fix the warning :)

Comment: Fixing warnings is usually a good idea.  Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3454066/2189500 ?  It talks about how to set section attributes.